# Replace the Outlier in a group with the mean of the group in a pandas series

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

In the following dataframe I want to replace the outliers in the **EMI** column with the **mode** of the group. Here's sample data.

| Id | C_Id | EMI |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1000 | 141 |
| 2 | 1000 | 141 |
| 3 | 1000 | 21538 |
| 4 | 2000 | 313 |
| 5 | 2000 | 313 |
| 6 | 2000 | 31528 |
| 7 | 3000 | 0 |
| 8 | 3000 | 0 |
| 9 | 3000 | 3000 |
| 10 | 3000 | 4000 |

I am expecting the output to be like this.

| Id | C_Id | EMI |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1000 | 141 |
| 2 | 1000 | 141 |
| 3 | 1000 | 141 |
| 4 | 2000 | 313 |
| 5 | 2000 | 313 |
| 6 | 2000 | 313 |
| 7 | 3000 | 0 |
| 8 | 3000 | 0 |
| 9 | 3000 | 0 |
| 10 | 3000 | 0 |

Comment: it is unclear how you define `outlier` as there are many way to estimate outlier

Comment: Since EMI remains constant each month, my idea was to replace outliers with the most frequent value.

Answer (score 0):

First step is to have modes calculated:

```
from scipy import stats
modes = df.groupby('C_Id').agg({'EMI':lambda x:stats.mode(x)[0]}).reset_index()
modes
```

Which will give you:

|  | C_Id | EMI |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1000 | 141 |
| 1 | 2000 | 313 |
| 2 | 3000 | 0 |

Then it depends on your definition of "outlier". If you simply meant outliers be a value different than mode, its simply:

```
df.drop(columns = ['EMI']).merge(modes, on=['C_Id'])
```

|  | Id | C_Id | EMI |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | 1000 | 141 |
| 1 | 2 | 1000 | 141 |
| 2 | 3 | 1000 | 141 |
| 3 | 4 | 2000 | 313 |
| 4 | 5 | 2000 | 313 |
| 5 | 6 | 2000 | 313 |
| 6 | 7 | 3000 | 0 |
| 7 | 8 | 3000 | 0 |
| 8 | 9 | 3000 | 0 |
| 9 | 10 | 3000 | 0 |

however if you have some criteria you can do:

```
merged = df.merge(modes, on=['C_Id'], suffixes=['', '_y'])
merged['replacement'] = merged.EMI.gt(merged.EMI_y*10) # use your criteria of outlier here
merged.loc[merged.replacement,'EMI'] = merged.loc[merged.replacement,'EMI_y']
merged.drop(columns=['EMI_y', 'replacement'])
```

Which will still give the same output for your example usecase however its comparisons will be based on the criteria you set:

|  | Id | C_Id | EMI |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | 1000 | 141 |
| 1 | 2 | 1000 | 141 |
| 2 | 3 | 1000 | 141 |
| 3 | 4 | 2000 | 313 |
| 4 | 5 | 2000 | 313 |
| 5 | 6 | 2000 | 313 |
| 6 | 7 | 3000 | 0 |
| 7 | 8 | 3000 | 0 |
| 8 | 9 | 3000 | 0 |
| 9 | 10 | 3000 | 0 |